# iphone reposition UITableView when hidding element above it

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, resize

I would like to make this:

[image]

So... when a user clicks on the search icon (top-left) the searchBar is set to hidden and UITableView is resized to top. How can I resize a table? Is it possible to achieve this not usign dimensions (like just set table's top to the navigation's bottom or smth)?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the table view's `frame` inside an animation block. It is up to you to calculate the correct dimensions of the frame rectangle.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
newFrame.origin.x -= self.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
newFrame.size.height += self.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
}];
```